# Joomla getting frontend template parameter from backend

Tags: joomla, parameters, get, frontend, backend

I am trying to make an option in the template I'm using, to select images in a previously specified folder by folderlist field and choosing which images to disable or not in an imagelist. For the purpose I am making a custom form field, on the base of the main imagelist.php provided by joomla, with an directory parameter set by the folderlist field.

The problem I'm experiencing is that I can't manage to access the frontend template parameters from the template settings menu in the administrator panel.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
    $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $templ = $app->getTemplate(true);
    $param = $templ->params->get('myparam');
    $this->directory = $param;
```

It only returns the admin template.

After some googling, I found that getApplication is not intended to really display the site application from the backend and administrator's from the frontend, but is rather an option to say what application should be run once, and it can't be changed after that first instance.

Is there a way to perform request to the parameter provided by joomla or should I check to the database for which params are curently set for the desired (used) template?

(The version of joomla I'm using is 3.3.0)

Comment: Nevermind, I've done it using database querying already.

Comment: Hi, can you answer your own question here, and then possibly mark as solved, to remove it from the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it is the best solution I provide but couldn't find appropriate joomla! provided solution to do it. For the way I stripped the data to get the parameter, I am sure there is better way to achieve it either.

The following code does do a query to the database, and retrieves the required frontend template parameter for later usage:

```
   //querying database for parameter
```

```
   $db =& JFactory::getDbo();
   $query = $db->getQuery(true);
   $query->select($db->quoteName('params'));
   $query->from($db->quoteName('#__template_styles'));
   $query->where($db->quoteName('template'). ' = ' . $db->quote('myTemplate'). ' AND ' . $db->quoteName('params').' LIKE '.$db->quote('%myParameter%'));
   $db->setQuery($query);

    $param = $db->loadRow();


    //extracting parameter from the result

    $paramTemp = explode(",",$param[0]);

    foreach($paramTemp as $k=>$p):

        $parm[$k] = explode(":",str_replace(array('"'," "),"",$p));
        if($parm[$k][0] == "folderlistParameter") $parameter = $paramTemp[$k][1];

    endforeach;

    //Passing option to filelist 

    $this->directory = "slideshow/".$parameter;
```

The above code, is put before:

```
$this->filter = '\.png$|\.gif$|\.jpg$|\.bmp$|\.ico$|\.jpeg$|\.psd$|\.eps$';
```

Line in imagelist.php file on which the custom parameter is added.